# How to wrap HTML content in CData (Java) for XSLT - XML to HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, cdata

Struggling here to wrap HTML content in CData, using Java. The ultimate goal is transforming XML to HTML via XSLT. CData is a requirement. As such, I want the XSLT to ignore the HTML but I'm obviously doing something wrong since it's not preserving the HTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<content>
    <records>
        <record>
            <param1>1</param1>
            <param2>25</param2>
            <param3>34</param3>
            <param4>b</param4>
            <param5>
                <p>this is html that should be wrapped with CData including the p tags.</p>
            </param5>
        </record>
    </records>
</content>
```

Here is the code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("test.xml");

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Element param5 = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("param5").item(0);
CDATASection cdata = doc.createCDATASection(param5.getTextContent());
param5.appendChild(cdata);

DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();

transform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "param5");
transform.transform(new DOMSource(doc) , domResult);
```

So, for param5, the XML file, just before transformation resembles this:

```
<param5> 
    <![CDATA[
        this is html that should be wrapped with CData including the p tags.
    ]]>
</param5>
```

When I want

```
<param5> 
    <![CDATA[
        <p>this is html that should be wrapped with CData including the p tags.</p>
    ]]>
</param5>
```

I am lost as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

The XSL is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="content/records/record/param5"/></h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the sample HTML output that I need:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <p>this is html that should be wrapped with CData including the p tags.</p>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying not to over complicate things. The basic problem is I want CData to include both the HTML content and the HTML tags. `getTextContent()` ignores the p tags. If there was a method that can grab everything inside param5, I'd be set.

Comment: "*I want the XSLT to ignore the HTML*"  What XSLT?

Comment: XSLT meaning Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformation. The basic problem is I can't get HTML markup to be wrapped by CData.

Comment: Michael knows what "XSLT" is, he obviously was asking you to show the stylesheet. Now that you did: Why is "CData a requirement"? What should the HTML look ilke?

Comment: CData is a requirement by the stakeholders for this task. I'll update it with the ideal HTML output.

Comment: If you change `<xsl:value-of select="content/records/record/param5"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="content/records/record/param5/node()"/>`, and apply this to your original XML without any pre-manipulation, you will get the entire markup contained in `param5` inside the `h1` node. I too cannot see why CDATA is required here.

Comment: The problem is I don't have control over the XSL stylesheet. The only thing I have control over is the Java code. CData is required because that's what I was instructed to use. This is not my own project. I don't understand why it's so difficult to get the HTML tags inside CData. I never had this problem in JavaScript. If I have to use a different design in Java, that's fine.

Comment: If you don't have control over your stylesheet then this question is not about XSLT. FWIW, I am not aware of any modification you could make to your XML to make the current XSLT produce the result you want; `<xsl:value-of>` will always return a single text node.

Comment: Maybe I could try to convert the param5 into a string (String Builder), place CData around the markup, and then convert the it back to XML. Maybe that might work. Thanks for our help, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a CDATA section with the markup of DOM nodes then you first need to serialize those nodes which can be done in Java either using a default transformer or the DOM Load/Save API. So I would create a document fragment node and appendChild all child nodes of the param to the document fragment, the serialize the document fragment to a string then you can use your code to create a CDATA section and appendChild it to the param.

Here is a simple example, the `import`s needed are

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment;


import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
```

then the code to read in the document and find the element is as you posted and the DocumentFragment is used to assemble all child nodes removed from the element:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse("sample1.xml");

        DocumentFragment frag1 = doc.createDocumentFragment();

        Element param = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("param5").item(0);

        while (param.hasChildNodes())
        {
            frag1.appendChild(param.getFirstChild());
        }
```

then the `LSSerializer` has a `writeToString` method:

```
        DOMImplementationLS lsImp = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation();

        LSSerializer ser = lsImp.createLSSerializer();
        ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);

        String xml = ser.writeToString(frag1);

        System.out.println(xml);

        param.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection(xml));

        System.out.println(ser.writeToString(doc));
```

The document then looks like

```
<content>
    <records>
        <record>
            <param1>1</param1>
            <param2>25</param2>
            <param3>34</param3>
            <param4>b</param4>
            <param5><![CDATA[
                <p>this is html that should be wrapped with CData including the p tags.</p>
            ]]></param5>
        </record>
    </records>
</content>
```

Someone at home in the Java world needs to tell you whether the cast to `DOMImplementationLS lsImp = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation();` is something reliable or whether you need to use the registry, as shown in http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/GeneratesaDOMfromscratchWritestheDOMtoaStringusinganLSSerializer.htm.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was asking for in the first place. I was planning on writing an answer using the `LSSerializer` class to serialize the node, then copy the the HTML markup and content and pass it to the  `setTextContent` method on the original node. Do you have any examples you can provide with the default transformer and/or DOM Load/Save API? Thanks, again.

Comment: @user3621633, I have edited the answer to show some code snippets that move the child nodes of the element to a `DocumentFragment` node, serialize that to a `String` and then create and add a CDATA section to the element.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see that. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question and that's why I was getting questions about using CData and XSLT but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: @user3621633 I still don't see how this is going to help you get the HTML output you are looking for. Transforming this result with the XSLT stylesheet you "don't have control over" will produce something very different.

Comment: The pay-grade above me said use CData so I'm using CData. That's what they want. It's not as if the XSL will change dramatically but it could be tweaked over time by another party. With the answer above, it works great and as long as the people above me are happy with it, I'm good :)